# HTML Table not displaying second column input field

Tags: html

Here is a sample code I got from my textbook and for some reason it's not displaying correctly. I just can't find the error.

It only show the second input text field "surname" and not the first input text "First name"  also.

```html
<html>
<head><title>Holiday Program</title></head>
<body style="background-color:cyan">
<form action="HolidayChoice.jsp"> <!--also try this with method="post"-->
<center>
<table style="background-color:lightblue”>
<tr>
<td>First Name<input type="text" name="clientFirstName"></td>
<td>Surname<input type="text" name="clientSurname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Location :<br/>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="ocean"
checked=”true”>Ocean<br/>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="lake">Lake<br/>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="nature">
Nature Reserve<br/>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="casino">Casino<br/>
</td>
<td>Accommodation Type :<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="1">Hotel<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="camping" value="1">Camping<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="caravan" value="1">Caravan<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="bungalow" value="1">Bungalow
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<center>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your textbook must be mega old if it still uses `<center>`. And it's doing what it's doing because the HTML is invalid. Try running it through a validator like https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. You're also using the wrong closing quote in `"background-color:lightblue”` and twice in `checked=”true”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `”` instead of `"` at line 6

Comment: There's more: also `checked=”true”`